# How to Hide Different Set of Row with the same Reference ID in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 related SQL table :

Purchase

```
id (PK),  
code,  
status (complete, void)
```

Receiving

```
id (PK),  
code,  
purchase_id (FK),  
status (complete, void)
```

With `Purchase` has Many `Receiving` (One-to-Many)

If the result of LEFT JOIN is

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Purchase.id|Purchase.code|Purchase.status|Receiving.id|Receiving.code|Receiving.status|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | PO001       | complete      | 1          | RG001        | complete       | X HIDE
| 2         | PO002       | complete      | 2          | RG002        | void           | X HIDE
| 2         | PO002       | complete      | 3          | RG003        | complete       | X HIDE
| 2         | PO003       | complete      | NULL       | NULL         | NULL           | V SHOW
| 3         | PO004       | complete      | 4          | RG004        | void           | V SHOW
```

The point is I want to show "Purchase", only if the "Receiving" status is not complete AND NULL.
So the result should only show PO003 and PO004.

PO002 should not be shown because it already has complete "Receiving"
while PO001 also will not be shown because it already has 1 complete "Receiving".

I hope you guys get what I meant. How do I query it on SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Put `WHERE` conditions in your query.

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, p.status, r.id, r.code, r.status
FROM Purchase p
INNER JOIN Receiving r ON p.id = r.purchase_id
WHERE r.id IS NULL
AND r.status != 'complete'
```

Comment: Thanks,  but the PO002 will be shown in that way. I don't want PO002 to be shown even it has "complete" status because PO002 has "void" status in other row.

Comment: `PO002` will not be shown as its status is `complete`. As the code states `AND r.status != 'complete'`

Comment: Sorry, my mistaken but that solution will hide PO003 that I need to show. INNER JOIN will not show the NULL one.

Comment: It would show 'PO003' as the two tables are not joined on r.id they are joined on p.id and r.purchase_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
select *
from  Purchase p 
join Receiving R 
on p.id = r.purchase_id 
where
r.id not in (
  select id
  from Receiving
  where 
  status = 'complete' or
  status is not null
)
```